# Getting a Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread, app breaking on compilation

Tags: python, python-3.x, fatal-error, gil, sqlite3-python

Although my application works just fine when running it from my IDE, compiling it presents this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x0000000104410580 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>

Extension modules: PIL._imaging (total: 1)
Abort trap: 6
```

Doing some research, I have not been able to find a solution and I'm sure its something small. I have been able to confine the issue to an initialiser in one of my files since commenting out this section allows the application to compile easily with no more errors:

```
def __init__(self):
        database_path = 'Login.db'
        absolute_path = os.path.abspath(database_path)
        print(f"Database path: {absolute_path}")

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(absolute_path)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        if not os.path.exists("Login.db"):# Create database if it doesn't already exist
            self.cur.execute(
                """     
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Login (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
                )
            """
            )
            self.conn.commit()

        self.user: User | None = None
```

Any insight would be appreciated!